# Get rid of client-config.wsdd in Axis

Tags: java, axis

I am setting up my test environment and I need to programmatically register my handler/transport instead of using a client-config.wsdd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
 <handler name="MyClient" type="java:foo.bar.MyClient"/>
 <transport name="MyTransport" pivot="MyClient"/>
</deployment>
```

Would you know if it's possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I've checked Axis sources and the following code solved my problem:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty(EngineConfigurationFactory.SYSTEM_PROPERTY_NAME, "foo.bar.MyEngineConfigurationFactory");
```

...

```
import org.apache.axis.EngineConfiguration;
import org.apache.axis.EngineConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.axis.configuration.BasicClientConfig;

public class MyEngineConfigurationFactory implements EngineConfigurationFactory {

    public static EngineConfigurationFactory newFactory(Object param) {
        return new MyEngineConfigurationFactory();
    }

    public EngineConfiguration getClientEngineConfig() {
        BasicClientConfig cfg = new BasicClientConfig();
        cfg.deployTransport("MyTransport", new MyClient());
        return cfg;
    }

    public EngineConfiguration getServerEngineConfig() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That's it. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: The example shown on [JAX-RPC client-side handler](http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/jaxrpchandler.htm) gave me some good insight when solving a similar issue. Just sharing my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

in the other hand, you can add a new client-config.wsdd file to resource directory.